# R: Calculate time it takes for a certain change in score

Tags: r

I have longitudinal data for multiple subjects. For each subject, I have between 1-25 measurements. Value is anything between 1-10. For each subject, I want to find the number of days it takes for a 2 point increase/ decrease in value.
example of data:

```
ID    Day    Value
1      1      7
1      3      6
1      7      7
1      8      8
2      1      4
2      2      7
3      1      9
3      3      4
```

I want to find the first occurrence of this change. What I would ideally find as output data

```
ID    Days  
1      5         
2      1
3      2
```

Ive made a column calculating the difference between a row and the next row within a group, and a column for the difference with each row and the starting value for that group, but I will still miss subjects who change >2 levels, like subject 1 in the example above.

I feel like this shouldn't be too difficult, yet I can't find anything on how to do this.
Thanks!

EDIT:
sample from my real data

```
        subjid                  Day                  Value 
 1: 11000-0458                    0                      6         
 2: 11000-0458                    6                     NA       
 3: 11000-0001                   NA                      4       
 4: 11000-0001                    2                      9      
 5: 11000-0001                    5                      9       
 6: 11000-0001                    8                      8      
 7: 11000-0001                   27                      6       
 8: 11000-0002                   NA                      4      
 9: 11000-0002                    6                      7      
10: 11000-0002                    9                      8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.table` option using `combn` + `diff`

```
setDT(df)[,.(Day = combn(Day,2,diff)[abs(combn(Value,2,diff))>=2]),ID]
```

gives

```
   ID Day
1:  1   5
2:  2   1
3:  3   2
```

---

**Update**

```
setDT(df)[,.(Day = c(combn(Day,2,diff))[c(abs(combn(Value,2,diff))>=2)]),subjid][!is.na(Day)]
```

gives

```
       subjid Day
1: 11000-0001  25
2: 11000-0001  22
3: 11000-0001  19
```

or if you want to keep `NA`, try the code below

```
> setDT(df)[,.(Day = c(combn(Day,2,diff))[c(abs(combn(Value,2,diff))>=2)]),subjid]
        subjid Day
 1: 11000-0458  NA
 2: 11000-0001  NA
 3: 11000-0001  NA
 4: 11000-0001  NA
 5: 11000-0001  NA
 6: 11000-0001  25
 7: 11000-0001  22
 8: 11000-0001  19
 9: 11000-0002  NA
10: 11000-0002  NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(subjid = c("11000-0458", "11000-0458", "11000-0001", 
"11000-0001", "11000-0001", "11000-0001", "11000-0001", "11000-0002",
"11000-0002", "11000-0002"), Day = c(0L, 6L, NA, 2L, 5L, 8L,
27L, NA, 6L, 9L), Value = c(6L, NA, 4L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 7L,
8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I keep getting an error message:
```
Error: All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.
```

I dont have a lot of experience using data table, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @MC26 Could you `dput` you data for the case you had erros?

Comment: The dataset is very big (>100.000 rows), so the output from dput is too large to see (or copy/paste). Is there another way that would work for you? I could share the top 5 rows (but that is basically the same as my sample data), just changed the subjid format (from ABC-123 to 1). Could that be the problem?

Comment: @MC26 Could you create a small dummy data (10 or 20 rows is fine) that follows the same format as your real data?

Comment: Ive added the first 10 rows of my real data, as an edit to the original question

Comment: @MC26 I updated the answer, hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

**1) sqldf** Self join each row to every row having the same ID and difference in value of at least 2 and then for each ID pick the matched row having minimum row id.  Take the difference in days between those two rows.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select min(b.rowid), a.ID, abs(a.Day - b.Day) Days
  from DF a
  left join DF b on abs(a.Value - b.Value) >= 2 and a.ID = b.ID
  group by a.ID")[-1]
##   ID Days
## 1  1    5
## 2  2    1
## 3  3    2
```

**2) dplyr** This follows a similar logic; however, as it is  not able to perform the complex join used in SQL it generates a much larger intermediate result from the left_join and then filters it down in a separate step.

By filtering in a separate step it no longer guarantees that every ID will be represented (unlike the SQL solution) so we right join the IDs at the end to fill in any ID without a change of at least 2.  For such IDs it will fill in Days with NA.  If we knew that every ID has a change of at least 2 we could omit this right join. In this example it does not make a difference because every ID has a change of at least 2 but this might not be so in general.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  left_join(DF, "ID") %>%
  filter(abs(Value.x - Value.y) >= 2) %>%
  mutate(Days = abs(Day.x - Day.y)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(Day.y) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  right_join(distinct(DF["ID"]), "ID") %>%
  select(ID, Days)
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##      ID  Days
##   <int> <int>
## 1     1     5
## 2     2     1
## 3     3     2
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "ID    Day    Value
1      1      7
1      3      6
1      7      7
1      8      8
2      1      4
2      2      7
3      1      9
3      3      4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```